# How to prevent two different windows services accessing the same file in runtime?

Tags: .net, windows, service, process

I have two windows services. One service moves files from ftp to a directory which includes sub directories include files. Another service reads these files from these directories and does some work taking long time. How can I prevent two different services accessing the same file while two services are working? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Mutex` to synchronize services.

```
Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "{Some unique Identifier here}");
```

A suitable identifier would be a `Guid`. You create one with [guidgen.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241442%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), which comes with Visual Studio.

And then your file access like this:

```
mutex.WaitOne(timeout, true);

// File access

mutex.ReleaseMutex();
```

This will work even accross different processes, because a mutex is created system wide.

The timeout will prevent possible deadlocks, if one of your services does not release the mutex.

EDIT:

Please consider, that using mutexes is **not** cross-machine compatible.

Comment: The issue with a mutex is that it is for synchronizing a single resource, here we could have more than one file to process at a given time, and locking the whole folder tree could hinder processing: when the first service is writing file "CRMDataFile.csv" the second service must be able to work on "HRDataFile.csv".

Comment: This only hinders processing if you have to copy files often. Secondly, `Mutex` won't work, if the services are not running on the same machine. It solely dependes on the requirements of the program. But I agree with you, that your solution is better, but also more complex to implement.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the cross-machine limitation, always good to have in mind. :)

Comment: I only noticed this issue after seeing your cross-machine compatible solution :D. I changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: What should I do if two services are in different machines?

Comment: Then you should pursue Pragmateek's solution. Otherwise you could try to implement your own cross-machine compatible mutex. This can be done by creating afile when entering the mutex and deleting it when you leave it. This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176231/mutex-across-network-c-net) offers another solution with message queues. You will find everything you need to know if you search for "mutex accross network" or somthing like that.

Comment: How can I use Mutex in two services? In one service it must be used like DMAN said. But in other service?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to synchronize both services you should have some way to **communicate** between them.

If you don't want to be bothered with too "complex" infrastructures like **IPC**, **message queues** or **web-services** you can use simple files:

- when the first service is done moving a file from the FTP, say `"someDataFile.csv"`, it can create a special metadata file, say `".process_someDataFile.csv"`, or a name with a **GUID** and the target file name kept inside
- to know if there is something to do the second service will check for these special files either by **polling** (more reliable I think) or by registering for changes in the folder with a `FileSystemWatcher`
- when it finds one then it processes the target file and when it is done it deletes the metadata file `".process_someDataFile.csv"`
- this is safe because if the processing crashes the second service, when restarting the service will notice, by seeing the metadata file, it has some work to do
- and in the worst case it will retrigger an already done job, but that should be easy to keep another trace of what was already done in a dedicated file